Exercise on Borel-measurability
Let $A$, $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $y_0 \in B$ be an accumulation point for $B$, and let $f: A \times B \to [-\infty, +\infty]$ be a $\mathcal{B}(A \times B)$-measurable function. Assume that for every $x \in A$, the following limit exists:
$$
g(x) = \lim_{y \to y_0} f(x,y) \in [-\infty, +\infty].
$$
(a) If $B$ is at most countable, can we conclude that $g$ is $\mathcal{B}(A)$-measurable?
(b) Without additional assumptions, can we conclude that $g$ is $\mathcal{B}(A)$-measurable?
For every $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, define:
$$
E_C := \{(x, y) : y = x \in C \}.
$$
(c) If $E_C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, can we deduce that $C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?
(d) If $C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, can we deduce that $E_C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?
Let $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $h(x, \cdot)$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, and for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $h(\cdot, y)$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.
(e) Can we deduce that $h$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$-measurable?
I have already solved the points $(c),(d)$ and $(e)$, but I am confused about the first two points, in particular, I don't understand how the hypothesis that $B$ is at most countable affects measurability of $g$ and consequently what difference there is in the question $(b)$. I'm stuck on these two points, any help? :)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

For (a) let $B={b_1,b_2,...}$ and define $f_n(x)=f(x,b_n)$. Write ${x: g(x)<a}$ using countable unions and intersections of sets of the type ${x: f_n(x) <c}$

For $(a)$:
By hypothesis, $f$ is $\mathcal{B}(A)\otimes \mathcal{B}(B)$- measurable, so you have that $f(x,\bullet)$ is $\mathcal{B}(A)$- measurable $\forall x\in A$.
Now, $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{eucl})$ is a 1-countable topological space, therefore $$\lim_{y\to y_0} f(x,y)=\lim_nf(x,y_n)$$ for all real sequences $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $y_n\overset{n}{\to} y_0$.
So, $g$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of $\mathcal{B}(A)$-measurable functions and so $g$ is $\mathcal{B}(A)$-measurable.
For $(b)$ it follows the same as $(a)$ even without $B$ at most countable.
